# Git commit only accept slash?

Tags: git, cygwin

I got this `error: pathspec '.\.filename' did not match any file(s) known to git.` when I tried to commit with file path include `\`, but now it only accepts path with `/`.

I am running windows 10 with cygwin, previously it works fine, and not sure what exactly cause this problem, any idea?

Just to be clear:

It works!

```
git commit -m "something" .\filename
```

It does not work:

```
git commit -m "something" ./filename
```

Comment: There is a very long discussion about this at [Cygwin Git with Windows paths](https://public-inbox.org/git/20181215043330.20162-1-tboegi@web.de/T/) which ended with some patches on 15/12/2018. Have you tried updating Cygwin recently?

Comment: In addition, are your sure you have works and not work the correct way around (as it doesn't agree with what you said at the start of the question).

Comment: Are you running the Cygwin version of Git or some other version?

Comment: Aren't your examples opposite of what you initially said?